# Layout gets ruined for short time then gets fixed after using gsap

Tags: javascript, css, gsap

I am trying to use gsap on the home page of a website.

```
.card {
    height: 10rem;
    min-width: 10rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-column: span 3;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 2rem;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(18, 133, 189, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, .1));
    backdrop-filter: blur(.75rem);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(.25rem);
    border: 0.15rem solid black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 .4rem 0  black;
    gap: 2rem;
    position: relative;
}
```

```
.card:first-child {
    left: -25vw;
}

.card:last-child {
    left: 25vw;
}

.card:nth-child(2) {
    left: 25vw;
}

.card:nth-child(3) {
    left: -25vw;
}
```

```
gsap.to('.card:first-child', {
    duration: 3, x: '25vw', ease: 'elastic'
});

gsap.to('.card:last-child', {
    duration: 3, x: '-25vw', ease: 'elastic'
});

gsap.to('.card:nth-child(2)', {
    duration: 3, x: '-25vw', ease: 'elastic'
});

gsap.to('.card:nth-child(3)', {
    duration: 3, x: '25vw', ease: 'elastic'
});
```

After intro the layout behaves like it should but once I visit another page(page here doesnn't mean new page it's a single page website with display:none when not in that page) and come back to the home page, the layout is still in -25vw for .card:first-child and so on.. for a brief second before fixing itself(the animation doesn't happen again and this is how it should behave). How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to experience the issue that you're facing?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier it's complicated. The problem paricularly is that  I have positioned the card elements in a bad position so that after gsap they'll come to the correct place. But when I click the home page again the cards remain at that bad position initially for a second before coming back which is the issue

Comment: I believe you. But having to visualize how what your page looks like, what goes wrong and how it's supposed to look like is just as complicated. So having an example of your code running helps a lot. Though it sounds like that you're elements are being rendered to their initial position after switching to the first page, correct? If that's the case, then you'll need to adjust to styles **after** the animation is completed, so that the elements have new instructions on how they should be rendered the next time they show up.

Comment: But isin't gsap adjusting the elements once the animation is complete? Cause I have given the desired position as the position mentioned in gsap

Comment: Sure, but once you use `display: none` then the animated elements will dissappear. Whenever you show them again, presumably with `display: block`, they will be rerendered with the provided CSS, which are the styles of their **initial** state. So `display: none` destroys the endstate of the animations. To prevent this, you'll have to explicitly set the styles of their endstate to the animated elements after GSAP is done. This way the browser will render their **updated** state instead of the initial.